# Xamarin Forms soft keyboard not in correct culture

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

Xamarin Forms 3.4 (iOS)
I have an `Entry` where I set the `keyborad` to be `Numeric`
In iOS, the soft keyboard has always a `,` as a decimal separator.
As a result, when the decimal separator of the device is a `.` the entry cannot accept the `,`, so I cannot enter decimal numbers.
How can I set the soft keyboard on iOS to have the correct decimal separator?
[image]

Comment: Could you share the screen capture of the keyboard?

Comment: Soft keyboard is simulator and other is real device keyboard. So in some countries they use commas instead of decimal ... example Russia. So your device region is different thats the reason. I'm an iOS developer and can not help you with Xamarine. But by changing the app region to US will solve your issue.

Comment: "So your device region is different..." is different than what? How can I make the entry to accept decimals?

Comment: Open `Simulator -> Settings -> General -> Language & Region` If you change it to `US` you will see `.` instead of `,` and if you change it to `Russia` you will see `,`. So it depends on country. Not all countries use `.` as decimal.

Comment: The screenshot is from a real device and not from a simulator. Probably, I manage the culture on my device but I cannot do that to the users of the app.

Comment: This is Russian device ... right? In Russia `,` is the separator of decimal numbers isn't it true?

Comment: No, it's en-US device. But the app needs to work correctly in any device.

Comment: If `UIKeyboardType is decimal` it looks like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIzXr.png)

Comment: I wish it was like that, but it's not! Even when I set the culture of the device to be "it-IT" it doesn;t change the comma to a dot.

Comment: Well this is not an issue so you should not handle this. Just save your value and while calculating use `NSNumberFormatter` to get the number by setting the current locale. This is what we do in iOS application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196870/discussion-between-thetiger-and-dimitris).

Comment: I cannot get the value from the entry with decimal, so I cannot convert it!

Comment: Of course you can convert.. I already shared the code and link in the chat discussion.

Comment: Few more info about this subject. In some cases the locale of the iOS is not valid for .net. For example the locale returned from an iOS device can be en-BE or en-ES. Because the returned locale (en-BE) is not valid in .net, I use a fallback which is en. The problem is when an Entry control is bound to a decimal field and the Keyboard of the Entry is set to Numeric, the soft keyboard that appears on the device has a comma for decimal separator (coming for the BE part of the device culture) which is not valid for the fallback culture (en). As a result, the entry cannot accept decimals.

Comment: @Dimitris Hi , then have you solved this phenomenon?

Comment: Yes, I did solve the issue. My solution works, but not sure if it's the best approach. I'm editing a `string` instead of a `decimal` and replace the separator depending on the culture that .net understands. If the separator is `,` I replace the `.` with the `,` and vice versa. If you need more info just tell me to post it.